# Limit of $\tan^{-1}(f(N))$ as $N\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am tasked with evaluating the following limit

\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\to\infty} \left( -N\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin^2(\theta/2)\sin(2\pi/N)}{\cos^2(\theta/2)+\sin^2(\theta/2)\cos({2\pi}/{N})}\right)\right)
\end{equation}

But have come up empty handed. If there's a calculus wiz that wants to take a crack at it, or just show my why it is in fact incredibly easy, I'd be very happy.

edit for anyone who comes looking: As Steven suggested below, the trick is to define $x=1/N$, and take the limit of

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0} \left( -\frac{1}{x}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin^2(\theta/2)\sin(2\pi x)}{\cos^2(\theta/2)+\sin^2(\theta/2)\cos({2\pi}x)}\right)\right)
\end{equation}

To second order in $x$, $f(x)$ is

\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin^2(\theta/2)2\pi x}{\cos^2(\theta/2)+\sin^2(\theta/2)(1-2\pi^2 x^2)}
\end{equation}

Inserting this in to the Taylor expansion of the $\arctan$ function, and plugging that into the limit gives

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-\frac{2\pi\sin^2(\theta/2)}{1 -2\pi^2 x^2\sin^2(\theta/2)} \right)= -2\pi\sin^2(\theta/2)
\end{equation}

Comment: Things I would suggest: swap the limit to infinity for a limit to 0 by taking $x=\frac1N$; then use the first couple of Taylor Series terms on $\sin(2\pi x)$ and $\cos(2\pi x)$, and finally plug the expansion you get from that into the arctan Taylor series.

Comment: Thank you, Steven!